# List comprehension to change numerous elements with different values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let us consider a list such that,

```
fruits = ['green apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'kiwi', 'red apples', 'kiwi']
```

If I wanted to change every element that includes the string 'apples' to melons, I would do,

```
fruits = [fruit if 'apples' not in fruit else 'melons' for fruit in fruits]
```

This gives,

```
['melon', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'kiwi', 'melon', 'kiwi']
```

How would I use a list comprehension, starting from the original list fruits to change every element that includes the string apples to melons and every element that equals kiwi to banana ie.

```
['melon', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'banana', 'melon', 'banana']
```

Is this possible with a list comprehension, or should i just loop over each element using a for loop and series of if/elif statements?

EDIT:

```
 for idx, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        if 'apples' in fruit:
            fruits[idx] = 'melon'
        elif 'kiwi' in fruit:
            fruits[idx] = 'melon'
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension can do it.

```
fruits = ['melon' if 'apples' in fruit else 'banana' if fruit == 'kiwi' else fruit for fruit in fruits]
```

Answer (score 1):

In *either* case, you should define some function:

```
def fix_fruit(fruit):
    # logic to decide what to return
    return fruit
```

Then you *can* use a list comprehension if you want:

```
[fix_fruit(fruit) for fruit in fruits
```

Or a loop, if you prefer.

Of course, you *can* do this "all at once":

```
[
    'melons' if 'apples' in fruit else 'banana' if 'kiwi' in fruit else fruit
    for fruit in fruits
]
```

But you shouldn't, because it's unreadable.

Better to do:

```
def fix_fruit(fruit):
    if "apples" in fruit:
        return "melons"
    elif "kiwi" in fruit:
        return "banana"
    else:
        return fruit

[fix_fruit(fruit) for fruit in fruits]
```

Comment: This is best IMHO. You can do it in a one-liner as shown in the other answers, but it makes it more confusing. Modularity is your friend.

Comment: Thanks! This is more readable, but I was looking for something that would swap the elements in the fewest lines possible. Normally I would of done something like the loop in my above edited question, is there any reason not to enumerate like this and instead use a function and list comprehension?

Comment: @Kyle "in the fewest lines possible" **why**? That is almost never a good reason to do something. Unless you are playing code golf.

Comment: @Kyle well, your loop does *something different*, it modifies the original list. The above create new lists. That distinction may not matter. Generally, creating functions with self-contained logic is a good practice. But there is nothing wrong with your solution above, really.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict then iterate through it, finding the first match, or defaulting to the fruit itself:

```py
swaps = {
    "apples": "melons",
    "kiwi": "banana",
}

fruits = ['green apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'kiwi', 'red apples', 'kiwi']
fruits = [next((v for k, v in swaps.items() if k in fruit), fruit) for fruit in fruits]
fruits # ['melons', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'banana', 'melons', 'banana']
```

Alternatively, you could use a list of tupes:

```py
swaps = [
    ("apples", "melons"),
    ("kiwi", "banana")
]

fruits = ['green apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'kiwi', 'red apples', 'kiwi']
fruits = [next((v for k, v in swaps if k in fruit), fruit) for fruit in fruits]
fruits # ['melons', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'banana', 'melons', 'banana']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super neat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one liner -

```
cfg = {'apples':'melons','kiwi':'bananas'}

[[v if k in fruit else fruit for k,v in cfg.items()][0] for fruit in fruits]
```

```
['melons', 'oranges', 'pears', 'berries', 'kiwi', 'melons', 'kiwi']
```